# how to send value of a php variable in java script

Tags: php, ajax

i am getting post data from docusign .to catch post data i am using file get contents. after parsing i want to send it to backend with ajax. how to send value of a php variable in java script.
my php code is

```js
<?php
//$postedxml = file_get_contents('php://input');
//$xml = simplexml_load_string($postedxml);
 //$xml[0]->EnvelopeStatus->Status;
$foo = "completed";
   echo "
<script language='javascript' src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js'></script>

  <script>

  jQuery.ajax({type : 'post',
           url : 'XXXX.XX.XXXX',
           data:{content:'<?php print $foo; ?>'},

            success : function(data,textStatus, jqXHR) {

              alert('you have succesfully sent the Agreement to');
            },
            error : function(errJQXHR, errTextStatus, errThrown) {

            }
        });
</script>"
```

if i send like this my data is getting  like this. but i want to send only hello. how could i do that.

Comment: What is inside `<?php print $foo; ?>` check it in the console to make it sure

Comment: what Sulthan tried to say you have to be sure that `<?php print $foo; ?>` is not empty.

Answer (score 0):

You're in the middle of a large `echo` statement when you do this:

```
echo "...
    ...
    ... <?php print $foo; ?> ...
    ...
    ..."
```

You don't need (or want) `<?php ?>` tags in an `echo` statement.  Just emit the variable directly.  It's a double-quoted string, so variables expand:

```
echo "...
    ...
    ... $foo ...
    ...
    ..."
```

Or you can explicitly concatenate:

```
echo "...
    ...
    ..." . $foo . "...
    ...
    ..."
```

Or, personally I think large `echo` statements are difficult to follow.  So go with your original intent and separate the markup from the PHP:

```
?>
    ...
    ...
    ... <?php print $foo; ?> ...
    ...
    ...
<?php
```

Putting everything inside of an `echo` statement unnecessarily wraps client-side code in server-side code.  This creates unnecessary overhead, limits what you can do with quoting, and generally makes the client-side code more difficult to read.

Answer (score -1):

Why would you want to send data from the server to the client to send it back to the server? Just do the thing entirely in PHP.

And if you really MUST send it over AJAX, you can just make a PHP file out of it and add the script tag as: `<script type="application/javascript" src="something.php"></script>`

Comment: actually i will get a post data from docusign connect. i want to store that details in backend of sap. we could not give our sap url directly in docusign connect. so . we had a public url in that we had a index.php from there we want to connect to backend

Comment: i have tried using curl but .. it is not connecting